# postgres update based on not null in 'item' column

Tags: node.js, postgresql

The code below calls `BOXES` db and selects `id` then orders based on `updated_at = NULL`, then earliest date previously updated. I would like to restrict the updating to rows with a particular value in `ITEM` column eg all rows with `ITEM = square`. Any hints?
Thanks

```
function updateOne (done) {
db('boxes')
.select('id')
.whereNull('updated_at')
.orWhereRaw('updated_at < NOW() - INTERVAL \'30 days\'')
.orderByRaw('updated_at ASC NULLS FIRST')
.limit(1)
.first()
.then(function (row) {
// No work to be done, so we'll return
 if (!row) return done()
```

Comment: Well, have you actually tried restrictung update to rows with particular values?

Comment: I've tried using this to select id of limited range but the program stops without error message

.where('300000 < id < 700000')